# How know the name and phone model

Tags: java, android

How do you know the phone on which the application is running? How do you know the version of the application that the user is using? Documenting the net I found that to know the version of the app you have to read the `AndroidManifest.xml` but. How do you?

Comment: Please google before posting questions. All I had to do was google for android.os.Build

Answer (score 2):

Try this out from the Build class

```
String myDeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
String myDeviceDevice = android.os.Build.DEVICE;
String myDeviceVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION;
String myDeviceProduct = android.os.Build.PRODUCT;
```

For more detail use this link [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the constants in [Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class.

- Build.MANUFACTURER
- Build.MODEL
- Build.PRODUCT

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as follows:

```
String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String model = Build.MODEL;
```

Manufacturer will you name of vendor n Model will give model number.